# VB.NET: Adding listener to checkbox column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview which has its first column as a datagridviewcheckboxcolumn.
What I want is to detect when user checks/unchecks any of the checkboxes within first column in the datagridview so I have thought in two solutions:

1)

```
    Private Sub OnDgvCellClick(sender As Object, _
                                e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick

    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        If Convert.ToBoolean(Me.dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("chkcol").Value) = False then
        ' Do some stuff
        else
        ' Do some stuff
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

2) Iterate over all the datagridview rows, and add a listener for checkedchanged event on the all checkboxes of the first column.

```
Private Sub AddCheckedChangedListener()
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.dgv.RowCount - 1
        AddHandler CType(Me.dgvDatos(0, i).Value, CheckBox).CheckedChanged, AddressOf OnCheckBoxCheckedChanged
    Next
End Sub
```

Which one is the best?

Comment: Why not simply assign the method to the "OnCheckedChanged" event in the markup?

Comment: I do not understand you at all. Could you please put an example? and what is the best option? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) 
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    If e.RowIndex < 0 Or e.ColumnIndex < 0 Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not an ASP app. It is just a classic WinForms.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try and tell  you something but what is the difference using your approach instead of using mine (case 1)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that way I know it works :)
If my answer was good please vote it up